# opencl Bitonic sort with 64 bits keys

Tags: sorting, hash, opencl

I used the nvidia sdk  Bitonic Sort and it works great for me.
BUT it is for 32 bits (uint) I really need ulong keys.
I have only typically 2^14 keys at a time and power of 2.
I searched all over but could not find any kernel designed for ulong.

I tried  to modified nvidia sdk  Bitonic Sort for using ulong keys but it does not work. The kernel does not crash but after de call to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel I got error : CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE

Can anybody tell me how to modify Bitonic Sort or another like RadixSort, or anything that can sort ulong keys?

---

I am running an NVIDIA Quadro 4000   OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.5.20 FULL_PROFILE
I used the original nvidia sdk BitonicSort.cl

## I just used"ulong" for keys and value input and ouput instead of "uint"

Thanks for helping

Comment: can you post the kernel you modified please? also which device(s) are you running the kernel on?

Comment: Unfortunately, these fast sorting algorithms are also rather complicated, making adjusting them to different datatypes difficult. I once used the [Intel bitonic sort](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/bitonic-sorting) and I found out that it did not work with values larger than 1 billion, even though it used uint.

Comment: @ Baiz I tried to trick it around by packing 30 bits on the keys and 18 more bits on the values and modify my comparator to use that extra info but it seem that the sorting is erratic. Why in the worl should such a powerful algo be limited to 32 bits. real shame.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made a work-around to suit my need.
I used 30 bits of the key and 18 HIGH bits of the value for the sorting.
I only changed the comparators (2 lines):

'#define MASK  0xFFFFC000  // to suit your need

from this: if( (*keyA > *keyB) == dir )
to this:   if(((*keyA > *keyB)||((*keyA == *keyB)&&((*valA & MASK)> (*valB & MASK)))) == dir )

It works fine.
But, still, it's a work-around and the question remains, what is we need 64 bits keys + a 32 bits (or 64 bits) value?